# Windows: Virtual Audio Cable too many processes

Tags: audio

I'm trying to add a second cable to VAC, but whenever I try to, I get the `Error 0/2404`:

[image: Error 0/2404]

I've quit all the programs that are using audio, but it still says there are 10 clients.

I was wondering if there was a way to set the number of cables on restart, so other applications wouldn't get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to go into the Line's playback and recording options in windows and make sure you have the following things unticked:

[image: Click for Picture (not enough reputation)]

*Allow Applications to take exclusive control of this device* in both the recording and playback
**AND**

[image: Click for Picture (not enough reputation)]

*Listen to this device* which is just in the Recording device.

Next, change go to VAC's control panel (make sure you start with admin rights) and click "Restart" (In the driver parameters) and then "Reset Counters". The outputs "streams" should reset to 0, not change the cables to however many you like, or change any of the others settings.

Answer (score 0):

The above fix does work!

On my system on the "Playback" tab, the Virtual Audio Cable Line 2 was marked as the "Default Communication device" (right mouse click on the output device to set this to you speaker.
Changing this caused VAC's line 2 to go "idle" and then I was able to change the number of lines.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer could be improved by including screenshots that would allow readers to see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It need Administrator access to configure the second line.

Start menu - hover the icon apps and klik right - choose MORE - Click RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR submenu

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155655)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).